# ios13 audio stream gets cut off in background

Tags: ios, swift, audio, ios13

I build an app for iOS that plays a shoutcast stream thru a html5 player.
that worked fine untill the iOS13 update.

now when i put the app in the background, after a minute the stream stops playing.

this worked fine in ios 11 and 12. Also this works fine in the xcode emulator with ios13.

i'm a bit lost, please advise :)

Comment: show us what you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

iOS saves itself the right to terminate your app unless "Background audio background mode" is specified explicitly.

In your xcode project configuration, go to the "Capabilities" tab, and select "Audio, Airplay, and Picture-In-Picture"

[image]

Also, you will probably need to define an "Audio session" right after the playback starts like so:

```
let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
try! session.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback,
                         mode: .default,
                         policy: .longForm,
                         options: [])
try! session.setActive(true, options: [])
```

You can read more about this here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/creating_a_basic_video_player_ios_and_tvos/enabling_background_audio

Comment: Thanks i will try it tonight. i did set the background mode allready, that did not change in ios 13, was allready so previously.

Comment: You also have to create the audio session or else it will not work.

Comment: also with the audio session the stream stops, did I mention that I use the web view to load a web player? also when I run the app on an emulator the stream works fine, its on the actual phone it stops playing when in the background.

Comment: I got the same results with the audio session created.